# Duplicate Variables in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, variables, duplicates

Can I not have duplicate variables in objective-C classes? Whenever I have two classes and name variables/methods the same it throws me a linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

How do I make two classes with each having a function of the same name?

Comment: Show the relevant portions of your .h and .m files. Most likely you've declared globals when you didn't intend to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are writing the variable declaration in the class file, but outside @interface block, if you do this inside @implmentation block or anywhere else you are just declaring a global variable.

Comment: Is this the same type of global variable as in java? Or does it mean something completely different.

Comment: In Java you can not declare a variable outside the class. You can have same behavior using static variables. So no, this is like global variable in C / C++, reachable from anywhere in your program using only the variable name, for this is the reason you can not declare more than one with the same name because, linking, you will get a duplicate symbol error.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for clarifying (sorry for the bad question)